# How to check if a program is running now or not by its title ? (using vb6)

Tags: vb6, process

How to check if a program is running now or not by its title ? (using vb6)

Example :

```
'check if there is a program contain a "Notepad" in its title

if (does "Notepad" running now ?) then 

end if
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
''# preparation (in a separate module)
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Public Function FindWindowHandle(Caption As String) As Long
  FindWindowHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, Caption)
End Function

''# use (anywhere)
MsgBox FindWindowHandle("Untitled - Notepad")
```

*Code above basically taken from [here](http://www.andreavb.com/tip020001.html).*

The exact window caption must be known for this. The function will return <> 0 if a window with the given caption was found, 0 otherwise.

To find a window whose caption *contains* a certain string, you will need to enumerate all windows and look for the correct one yourself. This process is a little more complicated, but explained in great detail here: [everythingaccess.com - Bring an external application window to the foreground](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Bring-an-external-application-window-to-the-foreground).

Comment: but I want to check if there is a program contain "Notepad" in its title because I don't know what is the document name(Untitled or anything else)

Comment: @faressoft: That's why I included the link to a blog post that explains how this can be done.

Answer (score 3):

Karl Peterson has some [great code](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/FindPart/) for this on his excellent VB6 website. It uses EnumWindows like Tomalak's answer (in the link)

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the handle of your app and a partial caption. It will return true if found.

```
Public Function GetHandleFromPartialCaption(ByRef lWnd As Long, ByVal sCaption As String) As Boolean

Dim lhWndP            As Long
Dim sStr              As String

GetHandleFromPartialCaption = False
lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)                                      'PARENT WINDOW

Do While lhWndP <> 0
    sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
    GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
    sStr = Left$(sStr, Len(sStr) - 1)
    If InStr(1, sStr, sCaption) > 0 Then
        GetHandleFromPartialCaption = True
        lWnd = lhWndP
        Exit Do
    End If
    lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
Loop
```

End Function

Comment: You should also include the WIN API function declarations.

Answer (score -3):

Now right click on taskbar and click task manager. Now show your running program.